# Using PHP - Add an additional subarray

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays.  The first array consists of a device with different subarrays with different details. The second array has 1 or more rows of item details.  Both arrays have a common field of "hostid".  How can I take the first array and add a new subarray called items and append all rows from array 2 where the "hostid" matches?

**Array 1**

```
0:
host: "4303-CAM-01.1"
hostid: "11367"
interfaces: (2) [{…}, {…}]
inventory: {vendor: "AXIS", model: "M5525-E", serialno_a: "1234567890", host_networks: "192.168.1.100", macaddress_a: "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX", …}
tags: (2) [{…}, {…}]
```

**Array 2**

```
0: {itemid: "263571", hostid: "11367", key_: "icmpping[{$CAMIP}]", lastvalue: "1"}
1: {itemid: "263572", hostid: "11367", key_: "icmppingloss[{$CAMIP}]", lastvalue: "0"}
2: {itemid: "263573", hostid: "11367", key_: "icmppingsec[{$CAMIP}]", lastvalue: "0.0009"}
3: {itemid: "263593", hostid: "11368", key_: "icmpping[{$CAMIP}]", lastvalue: "1"}
4: {itemid: "263594", hostid: "11368", key_: "icmppingloss[{$CAMIP}]", lastvalue: "0"}
5: {itemid: "263595", hostid: "11368", key_: "icmppingsec[{$CAMIP}]", lastvalue: "0.0010"}
```

**Desired Result**

```
0:
host: "4303-CAM-01.1"
hostid: "11367"
interfaces: (2) [{…}, {…}]
inventory: {vendor: "AXIS", model: "M5525-E", serialno_a: "1234567890", host_networks: "192.168.1.100", macaddress_a: "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX", …}
tags: (2) [{…}, {…}]
items Array(3):
0: {itemid: "263571", key_: "icmpping[{$CAMIP}]", lastvalue: "1"}
1: {itemid: "263572", key_: "icmppingloss[{$CAMIP}]", lastvalue: "0"}
2: {itemid: "263573", key_: "icmppingsec[{$CAMIP}]", lastvalue: "0.0009"}
```

Answer (score 1):

```php
$array1 = subarrays;
$array2 = itemdetails;

$array1['item'] = $array2;
```

Just create an array value in the first one and that equals to array 2.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to iterate through the first array, then check each item in the second one:

```
foreach($array1 as &$host) { // set the host as reference
    $items = []; // create a new array to store the items
    foreach($array2 as $item) {
        if ($item->hostid === $host->hostid) {
            $items[] = $item; // push the item to the empty array
        }
    }
    $host->items = $items; // update the items to the host
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Romi, here is what I tried based on your response...

$array1 = $deviceListTable[0];
$array2 = $itemListTable;

foreach($array1 as &$host) { // set the host as reference
    $items = []; // create a new array to store the items
    foreach($array2 as $item) {
        if ($item->hostid === $host->hostid) {
            $items[] = $item; // push the item to the empty array
        }
    }
    $host->items = $items; // update the items to the host
}
$tableData = $items; //New table to be used within table

Comment: So what's the result? One thing to point out: the `$items` array won't be available outside the outer `foreach` loop. So `$tableData = $items;` should throw an error.

Comment: No result, just an Uncaught SyntaxError.  So if I am creating this new array $items how can I make it accessible elsewhere?

Comment: What is the actual SyntaxError you are receiving? Also, you shouldn't need to access the `$items` array elsewhere. Your initial question was about adding the items from the second array to the item from the first array, which matches the `hostid`.

Comment: Error is VM1446:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: If I take both Array 1 and Array 2 and create this new array that contains the items, my end goal is to use this new array to display data in a table.

Comment: The error doesn't have anything to do with what we are talking about here. You are expecting to get the data in JSON format, but there is a problem with it, that's why you get the error.

Comment: So the error is no longer presenting itself, however the array is no showing the new items subarray?

Comment: I think I am confused by how to access the newly modified array?